# Unicorn Rails stack + Vagrant not serving some assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, vagrant, rbenv

I'm using a Rails Stack with **nginx + unicorn + rails** meant for a production server, but I'm staging it under Vagrant for testing purposes. While doing this, I encountered a strange behavior of the rails application, where very often one or other asset wasn't being served, i.e. application.css isn't being served and therefore the whole page is displayed without any styles applied to it.

I've googled the problem and found that Vagrant's FS driver isn't completely implemented and that would bring some problems while using Apache (haven't found any mentions to nginx). The solution to this problem was to disable sendfile by adding **sendfile off;** to the configuration file. And... it didn't work.

Further, I went through the logs (Rails, unicorn and nginx) and found that when the file isn't served, there isn't any mention to it in any of the logs. This brought me to the question that the problem can be in the mechanism used by Vagrant to share the **rails app** folder through the VM. As mentioned in vagrant's website, Vagrant uses Virtual Box's Shared Folders, which is quite slow comparing to other alternatives (as shown [here](http://vagrantup.com/docs/nfs.html)), and the workaround is to set up NFS Shared Folders. So, I decided to give NFS a try and the result was... the same. Unfortunately, some assets are kept from being served.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? I've searched for quite a while but haven't found any pointers additional to those I described here.

I'm using:

Mac OS X 10.6.8 + rbenv (to develop)

Vagrant + nginx + rbenv + unicorn + bundler (to stage)

**unicorn.rb**

```
rails_env         = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'production'
app_directory     = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), ".."))

worker_processes 4
working_directory app_directory

listen "/tmp/appname.sock", :backlog => 64
#listen "#{app_directory}/tmp/sockets/appname.sock", :backlog => 64

timeout 30

pid "#{app_directory}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

stderr_path "#{app_directory}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{app_directory}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

preload_app true
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/appname**

```
upstream unicorn_server {
        server unix:/tmp/appname.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Location of our static files
    root /home/appname/www/current/public;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
        break;
      }
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root /home/hemauto/www/current/public;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please post your Nginx and Unicorn configs?

Comment: Sure. Updated with the configurations. Do you want me to post nginx.conf also? It's the default one though. One more thing, I'm using a very similar configuration in a production server and it works well!

Comment: Update: I think I found out what the problem is (more or less). I found that this problem only happens if I drop the SSH session, which may have something to do with the VM management made by VirtualBox. I'll leave the question open for a couple of days to allow further explanations and then I'll close it.

Comment: What do you mean "only happens if I drop the SSH session"? I'm having this same issue but using vagrant+virtualbox+docker+unicorn/thin. Not using nginx and apache.

Comment: I'm having this issue right now as well, does anyone have a more definitive solution?